# Link error and I can't see why I'm getting it

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I know loads of people have asked this question many of times but, however, I'm totally lost here. I know why linker errors occur but can't seem to see what the problem is here.
Any help pointing out my mistake would be great!

[Picture of linker errors](http://prntscr.com/9xgpoe)

Header:

```
#ifndef DOWNLOAD_H
#define DOWNLOAD_H
#include <Windows.h>

class Download {
public:

    Download();
    Download(const char *URL, const char *FILE_NAME);
    ~Download();

    LPCTSTR getURL() const;
    LPCTSTR getFileName() const;

    void setUrl(const char &URL) const;
    void setFileName(const char &FILE_NAME) const;

    void downloadFile();

private:
    struct data_T;
};
#endif // DOWNLOAD_H
```

Cpp file:

```
#include "download.h"

struct Download::data_T {
    const LPCTSTR &URL;
    const LPCTSTR &FILE_NAME;
} *data;

Download::Download(){}

Download::Download(const char *URL, const char *FILE_NAME)
{
    &data->FILE_NAME = &FILE_NAME;
    &data->URL = &URL;
}

void Download::downloadFile()
{
    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile (0, &data.URL, &data.FILE_NAME, 0, 0);
    switch (hr)
    {
    case S_OK:                       cout << "Successful download\n";           break;
    case E_OUTOFMEMORY:              cout << "Out of memory error\n";           break;
    case INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE:    cout << "Cannot access server data\n";     break;
    default:    cout << "Unknown error\n";    break;
    }
    printf("%x",hr);
}

void Download::setUrl(const LPCTSTR &URL) {  &data.URL = URL; }
void Download::setFileName(const LPCTSTR &FILE_NAME) { &data.FILE_NAME =     FILE_NAME; }

LPCTSTR Download::getUrl() const { return &data.URL; }
LPCTSTR Download::getFileName() const { return &data.FILE_NAME; }

Download::~Download()
{
    delete this->data_T;
    delete &data;
}
```

And this is how I initialize the class object and call a function:

```
 Download dl("https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm9pszogafgm3e2/Cache_ver.txt?dl=0", "CACHE");
 dl.downloadFile();
```

Thanks in advanced!

P.s if you see anything that I'm doing wrong with pointers or anything for that matter, please point them out to me as I'm currently in university learning CPP for my course: computer games development, and it's really new to me(only used java before going there). 
Thanks again :)

Comment: most likely you didn't add `download.cpp` to your compile list.

Comment: Is the CPP file actually in your project? Did you somehow accidentally disable it from being compiled?

Comment: Yes it's within the project and defined correctly as far as I know. http://prntscr.com/9xgtxc

Comment: Please _don't_ post links to images of text. Simply paste the text directly into your question, where it's far more useful and imposes the burden upon you, rather than those seeking to answer your question. Also, external sites can go down, thus rendering your question useless. It only takes a moment to copy/paste the output window, before editing such that the format/contained info are useful. ;)

Comment: Sorry I won't do that again. Just thought that was the easiest/fastest way of showing them. Thanks for letting me know though as I'm pretty new to this stackoverflow. Btw there was no need for you to neg me just for that lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building the executable, you need to link the specific libraries or the object files that contain the functions reported in the link error.

Comment: Yeah I know that now but thanks for the response though :) *If you notice above I used a preprocessor macro to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What comes *before* those link errors?

This line `delete this->data_T;` shouldn't compile, so my guess is that there is a compile error reported somewhere earlier, no object file is generated for `download.cpp`, then the linker complains about a missing object file and reports the unresolved functions.

> if you see anything that I'm doing wrong with pointers or anything for that matter, please point them out to me

One advice: whatever compiler you are using, turn the warning level to the highest and watch closely everything it reports. There are several issues `struct data_T;`, `*data` not initialized in the posted code, `&data->FILE_NAME = &FILE_NAME;`,  `delete &data;` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I've removed a lot of the pointers now and I've finally got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issues I had with the linker errors Not really totally sure what the issue was but anyway here's what my code looks like now.

```
#include "download.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <urlmon.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

using namespace std;

Download::Download(){}

Download::Download(const LPCTSTR URL, const LPCTSTR FILE_NAME)
{
    data_T.FILE_NAME = FILE_NAME;
    data_T.URL = URL;
}

void Download::downloadFile()
{
    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(0, data_T.URL, data_T.FILE_NAME, 0, 0);
    switch (hr)
    {
    case S_OK:
        cout << "Successful download\n";
        break;
    case E_OUTOFMEMORY:
        cout << "Out of memory error\n";
        break;
    case INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE:
        cout << "Cannot access server data\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Unknown error\n";
        break;
    }
    printf("%x",hr);
}

void Download::setURL(const LPCTSTR URLt) {  data_T.URL = URLt; }
void Download::setFileName(const LPCTSTR FILE_NAMEt) { data_T.FILE_NAME = FILE_NAMEt; }

LPCTSTR Download::getURL() const { return data_T.URL; }
LPCTSTR Download::getFileName() const { return data_T.FILE_NAME; }

Download::~Download(){  delete &data_T; }

class Download
{
public:
    Download();
    Download(const LPCTSTR URL, const LPCTSTR FILE_NAME);
    ~Download();
    LPCTSTR getURL() const;
    LPCTSTR getFileName() const;

    void setURL(const LPCTSTR URL);
    void setFileName(const LPCTSTR FILE_NAME);

    void downloadFile();

private:
        struct URLData {
            LPCTSTR URL;
            LPCTSTR FILE_NAME;
        } data_T;
};

#endif // DOWNLOAD_H
```

For some reason though I can only initialize the class with the default constructor and not the constructor with parameters. I'm trying to figure out the issue now but if anyone else has got anything they say to help me improve on what I have written, it would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: `I can only initialize the class with the default constructor and not the constructor with parameters` Why do you think you need the `&` reference in `const LPCTSTR &URL`? Also, I'd be surprised if this `Download::~Download(){  delete &data_T; }` compiled and executed without warnings/errors.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, please?

Comment: (a) Why not simply `const LPCTSTR URL`? (b) You generally need to `delete` objects that you `new`'d.